# first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE of first order:

\begin{align} y^{'}= y^{2}+x, & \text{where }  y^{'}=\frac{dy}{dx} \end{align}

Is there any exact mehod to solve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Maple gives the answer in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: tanks, but I don't use Maple or Matlap or any program, I ask if there any hand method ?

Comment: I imaging you could solve this using a power series solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of function $\displaystyle y=-\frac{v'}{v}$. This transforms your differential equation into *linear* equation
$$v''+xv=0$$
which is solvable in terms of [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) (it is essentially Airy equation with $x\leftrightarrow -x$):
$$v(x)=C_1\mathrm{Ai}(-x)+C_2\mathrm{Bi}(-x).$$

Comment: now, if the initial condition is $ y(0)=0$ , after transformation it will be two conditions $v^{'}(0)=0 and v(0)=0$, right?

Comment: @Soul You are welcome. $y(0)=0$ means $v'(0)=0$. Then from the known series for Airy functions I find (but this is not double-checked) $C_1=\sqrt{3}\,C_2$.